# MS Access VBA using ReDim Preserve to increase the size of an array when needed( as in within a button click event handler method or within a loop )

Tags: arrays, vba, ms-access, dimensions

I'm new to Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2013 Access.

I am developing an application using:

-Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2013 Access

I my VBA Editor, I have the following Class Module:

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Database

Private cntrollingPersonFullNameProp As String
Private cntrollingPersonIsNameAddressProvidedProp As String
Private cntrollingPersonIsDOBProvidedProp As String
Private cntrollingPersonIsTaxResidenceProvidedProp As String
Private cntrollingPersonIsControllingPersonTypeProvidedProp As String
Private cntrollingPersonIsSignedAndDatedProp As String

Public Property Get CntrollingPersonFullName() As String
    CntrollingPersonFullName = cntrollingPersonFullNameProp
End Property

Public Property Let CntrollingPersonFullName(lCntrollingPersonFullName As String)
    cntrollingPersonFullNameProp = lCntrollingPersonFullName
End Property

Public Property Get CntrollingPersonIsNameAddressProvided() As String
    CntrollingPersonIsNameAddressProvided = cntrollingPersonIsNameAddressProvidedProp
End Property

Public Property Let CntrollingPersonIsNameAddressProvided(lCntrollingPersonIsNameAddressProvided As String)
    cntrollingPersonIsNameAddressProvidedProp = lCntrollingPersonIsNameAddressProvided
End Property

Public Property Get CntrollingPersonIsDOBProvided() As String
    CntrollingPersonIsDOBProvided = cntrollingPersonIsDOBProvidedProp
End Property

Public Property Let CntrollingPersonIsDOBProvided(lCntrollingPersonIsDOBProvided As String)
    cntrollingPersonIsDOBProvidedProp = lCntrollingPersonIsDOBProvided
End Property

Public Property Get CntrollingPersonIsTaxResidenceProvided() As String
    CntrollingPersonIsTaxResidenceProvided = cntrollingPersonIsTaxResidenceProvidedProp
End Property

Public Property Let CntrollingPersonIsTaxResidenceProvided(lCntrollingPersonIsTaxResidenceProvided As String)
    cntrollingPersonIsTaxResidenceProvidedProp = lCntrollingPersonIsTaxResidenceProvided
End Property

Public Property Get CntrollingPersonIsControllingPersonTypeProvided() As String
    CntrollingPersonIsControllingPersonTypeProvided = cntrollingPersonIsControllingPersonTypeProvidedProp
End Property

Public Property Let CntrollingPersonIsControllingPersonTypeProvided(lCntrollingPersonIsControllingPersonTypeProvided As String)
    cntrollingPersonIsControllingPersonTypeProvidedProp = lCntrollingPersonIsControllingPersonTypeProvided
End Property

Public Property Get CntrollingPersonIsSignedAndDated() As String
    CntrollingPersonIsSignedAndDated = cntrollingPersonIsSignedAndDatedProp
End Property

Public Property Let CntrollingPersonIsSignedAndDated(lCntrollingPersonIsSignedAndDated As String)
    cntrollingPersonIsSignedAndDatedProp = lCntrollingPersonIsSignedAndDated
End Property
```

In the Form code file,

```
Dim cntrollingPersonsArray()  As CntrollingPerson


Private Sub AddControllingPersonBtn_Click()
     Dim cntrlPerson As New CntrollingPerson
    cntrlPerson.CntrollingPersonFullName =  …….
    cntrlPerson.CntrollingPersonIsNameAddressProvided =  …..

  ReDim Preserve cntrollingPersonsArray(UBound(cntrollingPersonsArray)+ 1)   
cntrollingPersonsArray(UBound(cntrollingPersonsArray)) = cntrlPerson 

 End Sub
```

The application throws the:

'91' Object variable or With block variable not set

at the following line

```
cntrollingPersonsArray(UBound(cntrollingPersonsArray)) = cntrlPerson
```

I've tried a bunch of different code modifications

```
ReDim Preserve cntrollingPersonsArray(UBound(cntrollingPersonsArray))
```

or

```
ReDim Preserve cntrollingPersonsArray(0 to UBound(cntrollingPersonsArray))
```

or

```
 ReDim Preserve cntrollingPersonsArray(1 to UBound(cntrollingPersonsArray))
```

Could someone please show me what steps to take in order to correct the aforementioned problem?

Comment: Use `Set` when assigning an object

Comment: Rule of thumb, if you don't know how many items you're going to end up with, don't use an array. `ReDim Preserve` in a loop is criminally inefficient!

Comment: Why was this tagged [tag:vbscript]? What’s worse, why did no one bother to [edit] the tags?

Comment: Sorry, I'm naïve about MS Access.  Isn't the MS Access's VBA Editor's VBScript or is it Visual Basic?  Sorry, like I said I am a newbie with MS Access. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a collection object instead of an array. All your problems are solved!

EXAMPLE:

```
Option Explicit

Private cntrollingPersons As New Collection

Private Sub AddControllingPersonBtn_Click()
    Dim cntrlPerson As New CntrollingPerson
    cntrlPerson.CntrollingPersonFullName = ""
    cntrlPerson.CntrollingPersonIsNameAddressProvided = ""

    cntrollingPersons.Add cntrlPerson
End Sub
```

RELATED READING: https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-collections/